# Position Absolute div going outside

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set overlay at bottom of my image. I am using latest Bootstrap 5. I am getting output like this image:

[image]

You can see in last image that overlay black color is going outside of image and my column. I am trying to fix it from last some minutes but does not getting idea. Let me know if someone here can help me for solve the puzzle.

Thanks!

```css
.slider-img {
  position: relative;
}

.img-fluid {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* Black see-through */
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider-img:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 slider-img">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" class="img-fluid h-100" alt="Latest Hindi Status">
        <div class="overlay">My Name is John</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 slider-img">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" class="img-fluid h-100" alt="Latest Hindi Status">
        <div class="overlay">My Name is John</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 slider-img">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" class="img-fluid h-100" alt="Latest Hindi Status">
        <div class="overlay">My Name is John</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your absolutely-positioned element doesn't know about the padding on the parent column.

It's generally best to not tangle your content up with your grid. Put your content *inside* the grid. You could also apply sizing to the overlays, but this is ultimately simpler.

Other tips:

- Bootstrap has a class for relative positioning. No need to write your own.
- It's not wise to override core Bootstrap classes such as `img-fluid`. Add a custom class instead.

```css
.overlay-image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);  /* Black see-through */
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.overlay-box:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="position-relative overlay-box">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" class="img-fluid overlay-image h-100" alt="Latest Hindi Status">
          <div class="overlay">My Name is John</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="position-relative overlay-box">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" class="img-fluid overlay-image h-100" alt="Latest Hindi Status">
          <div class="overlay">My Name is John</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="position-relative overlay-box">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" class="img-fluid overlay-image h-100" alt="Latest Hindi Status">
          <div class="overlay">My Name is John</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change the code structure, we can adjust the overlay css. Hope this helps.  : )

We can use gutters size in bootstrap.

`--bs-gutter-x` is in Bootstrap 5 Base and you can find it in **[bootstrap.css](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.css)**.

You can find [using CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) and [how we can use it with `var()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var).

Here's the code:

```css
.slider-img {
  position: relative;
}

.img-fluid {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* Black see-through */
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: calc(100% - var(--bs-gutter-x));
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
}

.slider-img:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 slider-img">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" class="img-fluid h-100" alt="Latest Hindi Status">
        <div class="overlay">My Name is John</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 slider-img">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" class="img-fluid h-100" alt="Latest Hindi Status">
        <div class="overlay">My Name is John</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 slider-img">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" class="img-fluid h-100" alt="Latest Hindi Status">
        <div class="overlay">My Name is John</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm struggling to find documentation of this particular Bootstrap variable. A link would be a great addition to this answer.